# Concatenar elementos de un array con un separador pero con el último diferente

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Tengo una lista de formatos `['pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'tif', 'tiff', 'txt']` y quiero pasarlo a una cadena así :

```
pdf, jpg, png, gif, tif, tiff **y** txt
```

Las comas lo hice con un `.join(' ,')`, pero no encuentro una forma practica para colocar el 'y' en el ultimo elemento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizarlo con una combinación de la función [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/join), que te permite la unión de elementos de un array, y de la función [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/slice), la cual te devuelve una copia de una parte del array.

En este caso, lo que tendrás que hacer será hacer un `join` de todos los elementos excepto el último para poder agregar la concatenación especial para el último y es por ello por lo que utilizaremos la función `slice`, obteniendo primero todos los valores hasta el penúltimo `.slice(0, -1)` y finalmente obtener el último. Con el -1 indicamos que empiece a contar por el final del array.

```js
var formatos = ['pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'tif', 'tiff', 'txt'];
var formatosEnTexto = formatos.slice(0, -1).join(', ') + ' y ' + formatos.slice(-1);

console.log(formatosEnTexto);
```